# Compare std_logic_vector to multiple constants

Tags: vhdl

I have an if clause where I want to compare a 6-bit std_logic_vector with multiple constant arbitrary (i.e. not running numbers) 6-bit values. I know I can use "|" in case structures, but is there a way of shortening the following whilst keeping the if statement? I am not 100% sure but I think the rest of the design is using VHDL93.

```
if not (de_inst(31 downto 30) = FMT3 and (
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = LDSB or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = LDSH or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = LDUB or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = LDUH or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = LD or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = LDD or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = STB or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = STH or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ST or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ISTD or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = IAND or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ANDN or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = IOR or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ORN or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = IXOR or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = IXNOR or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ISLL or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ISRL or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ISRA or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = IADD or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = ISUB or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = UMUL or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = SMUL or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = UDIV or
  de_inst(24 downto 19) = SDIV )) then
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, it would be great if you left a comment with reason for giving a downvote, so the question can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VHDL allows you to write it at a higher level, where you make a "set" of all the instructions and then check if the signal has the value of one of these instructions, for example along the lines of:

```
subtype inst_t is std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
constant LDSB  : inst_t := "000000";  -- Just some value
...
type inst_array_t is array(natural range <>) of inst_t;
constant INST_SET : inst_array_t := (LDSB, ...);
...
function in_set(sig : inst_t; set : inst_array_t) return boolean is
  variable res_v : boolean;
begin
  res_v := FALSE;
  for idx in set'range loop
    res_v := res_v or (sig = set(idx));
  end loop;
  return res_v;
end function;
...
if not ((de_inst(31 downto 30) = FMT3) and 
        in_set(de_inst(24 downto 19), INST_SET)) then
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and just looks a lot more elegant than my initial approach :)